# Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined in IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, scrollview

I am getting Error " Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of undefined in IONIC"
My IONIC Version- 2.1.12.

I use [Ion-affix](https://github.com/aliok/ion-affix) plugin in my app  for fix the header in top.

Error:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Please add some code here

Comment: Where you able to solve this?